# FlyoutFooter ContentView with dependency injection in .NET MAUI app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui, .net-maui

I created a `ContentView` for the `FlyoutFooter` in my .NET MAUI app. In the footer, I placed an `ImageButton` with an icon that the user can use to sign out.

I'm also using dependency injection throughout the app so I registered both the `FlyoutFooter` view and its corresponding `FlyoutFooterViewModel` in the DI container.

The problem is when I try to tell the `Shell` to use the `FlyoutFooter` content view, it doesn't like it becuase its constructor receives a parameter -- see screen shot below.

[image]

The code behind for the `FlyoutFooter` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModels.Flyout"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.Flyout.FlyoutFooter"
             x:DataType="vm:FlyoutFooterViewModel">
    <Grid
      RowDefinitions="120"
      ColumnDefinitions="150, 150">
        <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            Margin="50,0,0,0">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="MISHRP"
                    Glyph="{StaticResource SettingsIcon}"
                    Color="White"/>
            </Image.Source>
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding GotoSettingsCommand}" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
        <Image
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
            Margin="0,0,30,0">
            <Image.Source>
                <FontImageSource
                    FontFamily="MISHRP"
                    Glyph="{StaticResource PowerIcon}"
                    Color="White"/>
            </Image.Source>
            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    Command="{Binding SignOffCommand}"/>
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</ContentView>
```

In the code behind for `FlyoutFooter.xaml`, I inject the view model -- see below:

```
public partial class FlyoutFooter : ContentView
{

    FlyoutFooterViewModel _vm;
    public FlyoutFooter(FlyoutFooterViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _vm = vm;
        BindingContext = _vm;
    }
}
```

The view model looks like this:

```
public class FlyoutFooterViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
   IDatabaseService _dbService;

   public ICommand GotoSettingsCommand { get; }
   public ICommand SignOffCommand { get; }

   public FlyoutFooterViewModel(IDatabaseService dbService)
   {
      _dbService = dbService;

      GotoSettingsCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(GotoSettings);
      SignOffCommand = new AsyncRelayCommand(SignOff);
   }

   async Task GotoSettings()
   {
      // Send user to Settings page
   }

   async Task SignOff()
   {
      SecureStorage.Remove("access_token");

      await _dbService.ClearAll();

      await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"///{nameof(Login)}");
   }
}
```

Any suggestions for handling this scenario?

Comment: Shell's inability to use DI is a [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70302148/199364). Maybe you can add the footer in code behind?

Comment: I see. I’ll figure out a way to go around this. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Sam I am facing this issue as well.  Did you find a way around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured out a way to do this.  Instead of the control with a view model, I gave AppShell a view model so I can use FlyoutFooterTemplate.

```
<Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Label Text="{Binding DABUser.Name}" BackgroundColor="Red"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Shell.FlyoutFooterTemplate>
```

I inject IServiceProvider into AppShell

```
public AppShell(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
```

and then set the BindingContext to the view model I want

```
BindingContext = serviceProvider.GetService<FlyoutFtViewModel>()
```

As I type this out, I am going inject the viewmodel into the constructor instead.

Comment: Your solution works. I thought about doing something like this but I also wanted to keep my flyout header/footer pretty simple because all I really needed was to access some data from my header/footer. For example, in the flyout header I display user's profile image and name. So, I was able to achieve this by using `MessagingCenter`. As a result, I didn't need a view model or worry about DI in this scenario.